# Uncaught Error: ko.mapping.updateFromJS, use ko.mapping.fromJS instead

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

#### Problem

I have played around a lot with the knockoutJS mapping plugin.

My problem can be best shown in the following jsFiddles.

### [This](http://jsfiddle.net/BBzVm/) one works. But [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ucrcG/1/) dont work.

I get the the error in the console

> Uncaught Error: ko.mapping.updateFromJS, use ko.mapping.fromJS instead. Please note that the order of parameters is different!

### Why i get this error and whats the difference in the fiddles ?

#### My Code

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({
    "State" : 1,
    "Text" : "Hello"
});

$("button").click(function() 
{
    var response = {
        "State" : 2,
        "Text" : "World"
    }
        
    ko.mapping.updateFromJS(viewModel, response);
});
    
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are **using different versions of the ko mapping** plugin:

In your working fiddle: `http://wiredwestwebdesign.com/knockout.mapping.js`

In you not working fiddle: `https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js`

And the method in question `ko.mapping.updateFromJS` was deprecated about a year ago in this changeset: [First part of removing the updateFromJS* calls](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/commit/bff3c1864a5fd45289933b35de1ef70af4aed6b5).

And how to fix this error:

Just do what the exception says: use `ko.mapping.fromJS` and watch for the parameter order:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(response, viewModel);
```

[Demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/ucrcG/2/)

Comment: Ah ok, how can i achieve that using the latest mapping plugin ?